# Thingsboard: bulk device creation

Tags: api, thingsboard

Can I create multiple devices in a single API request?

I can't find corresponding API methods in my Swagger UI, but I still do not lose hope..

TB PE v3.1.1

**UPD**

[[Feature Request] Add bulk device creation API method #4242](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/4242) created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found out by looking at the Swagger documentation, https://cloud.thingsboard.io/swagger-ui.html, ThingsBoard offers no endpoint for bulk creation (yet).

It is confirmed by inspecting the network requests done when you use the "create devices from a CSV file" feature in the web interface. A `POST` called is made for each line of the CSV.

So it means that if you want to massively create devices from a custom script, you need to execute the HTTP requests in a loop or in queue.